# Is it safe to use the PSU from a Sun Ultra 45 to build a modern system?

Tags: desktop-computer, computer-building

HI，I want to modify sun ultra 45 to fit modern computer components

I really like sun ultra 45

Hope the case relive in my life

Comment: You might be able to re-use the case - even if you have to drill/cut it to fit a modern mobo, but I doubt the PSU would be compatible with anything made in the last decade. I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKY_TxJj2Nc but I haven't watched it.

Answer (score 0):

Well. It won't. One of the reasons PC components are reasonably compatible is that they are mostly based on the ATX form factor and it's derivatives. Most workstations of tht era had their own standards.

From the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19127-01/ultra45.ws/819-1892-12/819-1892-12.pdf) the connectors look nothing like the standard [image], . It would likely be more logical to modify the case for a modern power supply rather than use the current old PSU for a modern build. I also suggest measuring and checking if a flex atx or other modern server psu might fit rather than an ATX

[image]

Comment: https://zayn.world/projects.html seems to be of potential use...